# How can I get my content to be scroll-able while maintaining my header and footer being in the same place

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I need to make it so though while my header and footer remain at the top and bottom of the page respectively, the content in the middle of my page remains scrollable. As it is right now the header and footer do stay but the content in the middle cannot be scrolled which I found out makes it not work on certain screens. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to mess with it and so far I have had not luck.

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <p> The Official Site of Victor Alam </p>
</div>

<body>

<div class="nav">
<ul>
    <li><Home<li>
    <li>Education<li>
    <li>Work Experience<li>
    <li>Hobbies<li>
</ul>
</div>


<img src="IMAGE" alt="Me" class="center">

<div class="info">
    <p> BLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAHBLAH BLAH </p>
</div>

</body>


<div class="footer">
<ul>
    <li>BLAH BLAH</li>
    <li>BLAH BLAH</li>
    <li>BLAH BLAH</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.header 
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    height:40px;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:120%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}

div.nav
{
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color:white;
}

div.nav ul 
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
    overflow:hidden;}

div.nav li 
{
    float:left;
}

div.nav li a 
{
    display:block;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:16px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

div.nav li a:hover 
{
    background-color:#111111;
}

.center
{
    padding-top:140px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:29%;
}

div.info
{
    color:black;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:20px;
}

div.footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;

}

div.footer ul {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:hidden;

}

div.footer li {
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    color:white;
}

The results are that it looks good on some monitors but on some it comes across as way to zoomed in and it won't let you scroll through the content.
```

Comment: body { min-height: 100vh;} might help

Answer (score 0):

To make a container scroll using css, add `overflow: scroll`. Below is an example of a very basic header, body, and footer where the header and footer stay at the top and bottom, while the body scrolls.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="content">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

.content{
  display:flex;
  flex-grow:1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

For working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Matthew_/90gLy6nw/6/

Answer (score 0):

Okk , So You can use the CSS property of `position:fixed;`

**Give the CSS Property `position:fixed;` to both the sections header and footer , which will be static when the screen will scroll**

---

**NOTE --> Don't Give the fixed property to the content div**

- First make the content div
- and some text

By doing this you make a another part of the page which is independent of other sections . Since all other two ( header & footer ) have Fixed position . and now only your content section will be scroll.